# Editing table in a word document via perl win32:Ole module

Tags: perl, win32ole

I'm writing a Perl script for Automating a certain process, in this script I need to edit a table in a word file. I am using Win32::Ole perl module but the problem is that I can't find a good documentation for the module. 
I need to know how to append rows at the end of the table and how to get the number of rows & columns of the table.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you want to add rows and columns in word? or you mean excel?

[here](http://search.cpan.org/~jdb/Win32-OLE-0.1709/lib/Win32/OLE.pm#EXAMPLES) is a example category and a documention of the module for an excel issue.

answered? :)

---

edit:

Some more Links:
Write Word Doc with [Win32::Word::Writer](http://search.cpan.org/~johanl/Win32-Word-Writer-0.03/lib/Win32/Word/Writer.pm) maybe a approach

furthermore here is an replacement example for word
[Solution to edit Word Docs with Perl](http://www.perlmonks.org/bare/?node_id=733792)

your wish is not trivial i think.. for example: if you want to edit an excel xlsx file with perl - this seems not to be possible atm..

Comment: i want to add rows to a table in a word document. 
I need documentation for the module for editing word docs

Comment: @MustafaAbdel-Khalik could i help you?